# Update / Deleting Custom Site Templates

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, modern-experience

I have created a custom site template in sharepoint online using the modern experience. However, there have been changes made that would impact future sites created with that template. Is there a way i can update the site template to accommodate the changes i have made?

Otherwise, if i delete the site template, will it delete the sites i created using said template? It would work just as well for me if i could delete the template, whilst retaining the sites utilizing it, and create a new template based on the changes I've made.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify how you created the site templates? There are a variety of tools, but OOB SharePoint no longer offers "site templates"

Comment: @Mike2500 I put " /_layouts/savetmpl.aspx" after the site collection name in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to apply a site template to an existing site.

In addition, site Owner can only deactivate and delete the Site Template that already not used.

Site Collection Administrator is responsible for the entire site collection and can deactivate and delete a Site Template that already used or not.

So you should be a Site Collection Administrator to be able to delete Site Template that already used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didnt really answer any of my questions. The main things i want to know are

 1: If i delete the site template, will the sites that were created with it be deleted? 2: Can i edit or make changes to an existing site template?

Comment: 1.The site will not be deleted.
2.We cannot make changes to an existing site template.